# Como filtrar resultados e recarregar a página/view no CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Tenho um código em CodeIgniter que pega um valor de uma `select dropbox` em uma `view` e leva a uma segunda `view` mostrando os resultados em uma tabela. Nessa segunda `view`, eu mantive a `dropbox` e o botão de `submit` ("Filtrar") e gostaria de que o usuário pudesse selecionar outro valor da `dropbox` e filtrar, recarregando a página com outros resultados a serem mostrados na tabela.
Eu fiz isso, mas a página não está recarregando. Eu acredito que devo botar algo no fim da URL para ser diferente a cada *refresh* ou algo do tipo, mas por enquanto sem sucesso. Alguma sugestão?

Model:

```
class TrackerModel extends CI_Model {
    function get_coordenadas($cliente, $filtro, $num, $offset){
        //SELECT * FROM `tracker_coordenada`,`tracker_veiculo` WHERE tracker_coordenada.veiculo_codigo = tracker_veiculo.veiculo_codigo AND tracker_veiculo.cli_cod = $cliente
        $this->db->select('tracker_coordenada.*');
        $this->db->from('tracker_coordenada, tracker_veiculo');
        $this->db->where('tracker_coordenada.veiculo_codigo = tracker_veiculo.veiculo_codigo');
        $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.cli_cod',$cliente);
        if($filtro !=NULL){
            $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.descricao',$filtro);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get('',$num, $offset);
        return $query->result();
        //$sql = "SELECT tracker_coordenada.* FROM `tracker_coordenada`,`tracker_veiculo` WHERE tracker_coordenada.veiculo_codigo = tracker_veiculo.veiculo_codigo AND tracker_veiculo.cli_cod = ".$cliente;
        //$resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
        //return $resultado->result_array();
    }
    function conta_coordenadas($cliente){
        //$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total FROM coordenadas WHERE news_id = $news_id");
        //$row = $query->row();
        //echo $row->total;
        $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.cli_cod', $cliente);
        $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.veiculo_codigo', 'tracker_coordenada.veiculo_codigo');
        $query = $this->db->count_all('tracker_coordenada');
        return $query;
    }
    function get_trackers($cliente){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tracker_veiculo');
        $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.cli_cod',$cliente);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class TrackerCtrl extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('tracker/TrackerModel');
        $this->load->model('FuncoesModel');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->language("label");
    $this->load->helper('form');
    }
    function index(){
    if ($this->FuncoesModel->VerificaPermissao("listar", "tracker") != "S"){
        redirect('principal/principalctrl/acessonegado');   
    }           
    $dados['titulo'] =  $this->lang->line('Tracker');
    $cliente = $this->session->userdata("par_cli_codigo");
    $dados['user_trackers_list'] = $this->TrackerModel->get_trackers($cliente);
    $dados['dinamico'] = '/tracker/TrackerView';
    $dados['filtro'] = $this->input->post('frota_list');
    $this->load->vars($dados);
    $this->load->view('/principal/PrincipalView');
    }
    function listar($dados=""){
    $dados['titulo'] =  $this->lang->line('Tracker');
    $cliente = $this->session->userdata("par_cli_codigo");
    $dados['filtro'] = $this->input->post('frota_list');
    $dados['user_trackers_list'] = $this->TrackerModel->get_trackers($cliente);
    $dados['dinamico'] = '/tracker/TrackerRelatorioView';
    //Paginacao
    $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/tracker/trackerctrl/listar/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->TrackerModel->conta_coordenadas($cliente);
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['first_link'] = $this->lang->line('Primeiro');
    $config['last_link'] = $this->lang->line('&Uacute;ltimo');
    $config['next_link'] = $this->lang->line('Pr&oacute;ximo');
    $config['prev_link'] = $this->lang->line('Anterior');           
    $dados['get_coordenadas'] = $this->TrackerModel->get_coordenadas($cliente, $this->input->post('frota_list'), $config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $dados["paginacao"] =  $this->pagination->create_links();   
    $this->load->vars($dados);
    $this->load->view('/principal/PrincipalView');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<? 
if($this->session->flashdata('msg')){
?>
    <div style="background:#FF0000; text-align:center" align="center">
        <font color="#FFFFFF"><?=$this->session->flashdata('msg')?></font>
    </div>
<? 
}
?>
<div class="row-fluid sortable">        
    <div class="box span12">
        <div class="box-header" data-original-title>
            <h2><i class="icon-eject"></i><span class="break"></span><?=$titulo?></h2>
            <div class="box-icon">
                <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead"><font color="#FF0000"></font><?=$this->lang->line('Ve&iacute;culo')?>:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="<?=site_url('tracker/trackerctrl/listar/')?>">
                        <select name="frota_list" id="frota_list" style="width:300px"  >
                            <? foreach($user_trackers_list as $opcao){?>
                                <option><?=$opcao->descricao?></option>
                            <? }?>
                        </select>
                        <br><br>
                        <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn_filtrar" name="btn_filtrar"><?=$this->lang->line('Filtrar')?></button>
                        <?=form_hidden($this->security->get_csrf_token_name(), $this->security->get_csrf_hash());?> 
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/span-->

</div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu `form` aponta para o método `listar` da classe `TrackerCtrl` onde o campo `frota_list` não é considerado ao popular a variável `user_trackers_list` através do método `get_trackers` da classe `TrackerModel`.

Talvez você devesse alterar o método `get_trackers` da classe `TrackerModel` para aceitar um segundo parâmetro (ex.: `frota_item`) e adicionar uma segunda cláusula `where` para filtrar por esse campo (ex.: `$this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.frota_item', $frota_item);`).

Você pode fazer isso de modo condicional, de modo a não alterar o funcionamento atual. Ex.:

Model:

```
...
function get_trackers($cliente, $frota_item = false){
    ...
    $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.cli_cod', $cliente);
    if($frota_item){
        $this->db->where('tracker_veiculo.frota_item', $frota_item);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    ...
}
...
```

Controller:

```
...
function listar($dados=""){
    ...
    $dados['filtro'] = $this->input->post('frota_list');
    $dados['user_trackers_list'] = $this->TrackerModel->get_trackers($cliente, $this->input->post('frota_list'));
    $dados['dinamico'] = '/tracker/TrackerRelatorioView';
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi, você está passando valores entre views para manter o selecionado e então fazer a filtragem, certo?
Porque não utiliza um pouco de Jquery e usa a função Ajax para trazer os dados dinamicamente sem dar o refresh?
Assim toda vez que o usuário selecionar algo no select dropbox ele chama a página que filtra os dados. 
Vou te passar o código.

Acrescente o Jquery aos delimitadores head

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Agora, no final de sua página, antes do /body adicione:

```
<script>
    $( 'select' ).change( function () {

        var idItem  =  $( this ).val();

        pesquisar( idItem )

    });


    pesquisar = function ( idItem ) {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: "sua_base_url/controler/metodo",

            data: 'idItem=' + idItem, 

            success: function (data) {

                $( 'tabela' ).html( data );

            },

            error: function(request, status, error){

                alert(request.responseText);

            }

        });

    }
```

Esses dados chegaram ao seu controller via POST, então faça o que quiser com ele e devolva assim:

$this->parser->parse('ajax/sua_pagina', $data);

Acho que isso otimiza seu sistema de filtragem.

Qualquer coisa estamos ai.